# How to get single value from NodeList

Tags: javascript, selectors-api, nodelist

Help me to obtain single value from Item from NodeList.
I want to map two NodeLists to array of objects.
I want to create a form that adds new book to the library with a function that dynamically put new author first and last names row to the form. But a can't understand how to take inputs from additional rows to JSON object. I found only this solution, but can't understand hot to get single value from querySelectorAll NodeList, and then create an author object.
I want to take object like this:

```
    const newBook = {
        title: 'title',
        year: '2000',
        authors: [{
               firstName: 'Name',
               lastName: 'LastName'
}]
    };
```

I want to take an object like this:

```
function Author(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstname = firstName;
    this.lastname = lastName;
}
const authors = Object.create(null);
const $author = document.querySelector('#formAuthor');
const firstName = [$author.querySelectorAll("#firstName")];
const lastName = [$author.querySelectorAll('#lastName')];
for (let i = 0; i < firstName; i++) {
   let author = new Author(firstName[i], lastName[i]); //here

    authors.push(author);
```

Here is HTML

```
<div id="createForm" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Add new book</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input placeholder="title" id="formTitle" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="formTitle">title</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="formYear" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="formYear">year</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6 author" id="formAuthor">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6 genre" id="formGenre">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="valign-wrapper leftBottom">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" id="createBook">Save</a>
        </div>
            <div class="fixed-action-btn">
            <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
                <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="btn-floating blue" id="addAuthor"><i class="material-icons">person_add</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1" id="addGenre"><i class="material-icons">library_books</i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additional row adding

```
function onCreateBookAddAuthorRow() {
    let $authorRow = document.createElement('div');
    let count = $author.childElementCount;
    $authorRow.className = 'authorRow';
    $authorRow.innerHTML = `<div class="row" id="authorRow-${count}">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="firstName" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="lastName" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat" id="deleteAuthor-${count}">delete</a>
      </div>`;
    $author.appendChild($authorRow);

    document.querySelector('#deleteAuthor-' + count).addEventListener('click', function () {
        $author.removeChild($author.lastChild)
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `$author`?

Comment: This is parent div of this form
const $author = document.querySelector('#formAuthor');

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the html as well.

Comment: yeah, I added a description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, You should not have multiple elements with the same id in the HTML

You could use `Array.from()` or the spread operator `...` to convert NodeList to Array as shown below

```
// consider converting the ID to a class like so,
const firstName = Array.from($author.querySelectorAll(".firstName"));
const lastName = Array.from($author.querySelectorAll('.lastName'));

// now if it div you might want to take the innerText or innerHTML to get the values. For input types use .value

for (let i = 0; i < firstName; i++) {
   let author = new Author(firstName[i].innerText, lastName[i].innerText);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for help!!

Comment: @Svyatoslav Ivanov , feel free to upvote / accept the answer (the tick below the voting buttons) if it helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I will have done this immediately, when will reach 15 points of reputation!

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I see now)

Comment: Not a problem @SvyatoslavIvanov happy to help! Cheers,